# Docker Desktop installation on WIndows causes InetAddress.getLocalhost().getCanonicalHostname() to return host.docker.internal

Tags: java

I'm using a Windows machine with Docker Desktop installed. My project does **not** live inside a docker container.

But as evident to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-263484, it seems that Docker Desktop has overridden my host file to function properly, and the following code now returns an incorrect hostname.

```java
InetAddress.getLocalhost().getCanonicalHostname() // host.docker.internal
```

This is my host file

```
#...
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.128.75 host.docker.internal
192.168.128.75 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Is there another standard method (that is cross-platform) to detect real machine hostname that works with Docker Desktop installations?

---

As mentioned in the linked issue and in Rob's answer, I could probably add an entry in my host file to mitigate this issue, but this might not work too well if the IP gets changed, and requires additional setup.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `getCanonicalHostname()` takes the first entry for your IP address. It's not the best solution, but if you add an entry for `192.168.128.75` above the one for `host.docker.internal`, that one gets picked up.

Comment: That could work, but it requires the program user to setup their host files which is not ideal. This is also mentioned in the linked issue. And it will likely not work when the assigned IP gets changed. Let me edit my question.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible in Java 17 and earlier. I tried using `NetworkInterface` and `InterfaceAddrss` but no such luck. Java 18 will add JEP 418 (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/418) with this class: https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk18/docs/api/java.base/java/net/spi/InetAddressResolverProvider.html. That can return instances of this interface: https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk18/docs/api/java.base/java/net/spi/InetAddressResolver.html. That appears to let you get a stream of addresses.